# What is a good user interface for managing real-time events?

Tags: examples, workflow

I need to build a web app to help a support staff manage a boat-load of incidents in real-time. Some events will be weighted heavier than others. And events need to be hidden once they've been addressed. Right now I'm thinking of just a weighted queue, but would love to see what others may have come up with.

Any good UIs or UI constructs out there that help people deal with real-time events?

Comment: Hi Ian, could you try rephrasing your question to ask a more specific question? Asking for examples of UIs is one thing but I think you'd be better helped if we could assist you with your sppecific problem. Try adding more detail about the app you're trying to design.

Comment: Done. Was this helpful?

Comment: What is the nature of the reports and the responses?  Is an incident something like "911 call" (incomplete info, respond immediately) or more like "update virus packages" (do on 1000 computers sometime today)?  Is this a planning app or a reactive app?

Comment: incomplete and reactive (real-time)

Comment: Do users choose incidents to open/address or does everybody just take the next one when ready?  Do incidents get updated once submitted (since reports are incomplete) and, if so, do users need to know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had to do something similar ( 13 years ago ) we went down the route of a weighted list. I think this would still work, in some form, because most people who use Google are used to a weighted list - the most important/relevant entries are at the top.

However, also consider issues around how the system will be used - what do users need to do to entries on the list? The real issues for large, volatile, real-time lists are making sure that everyone has a correct list at all times. Alongside this, you need to ensure that any individual sees the information relevant to them - which may mean different people have different lists.

Good luck! Real-time operations are very tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Ian, sorry my answer is not going to be very helpful but I was up against same problem when researching event management systems for the legal industry. Event management efficiency is is this industry's most vital component. Events here are any kind of court hearing, motion, deposition, basically anything related to a court Case. Because these products are on subscription model it's hard to find screenshots, but a few subscriptions for demos might get you moving in the right direction. Prolaw comes to mind, as well as ClinicYou from event management for clinicians angle.

Also, large hotel chains have similar interfaces for their events/catering side of business. Wish I could give you the actual screenshots, sorry, you'll have to do some digging.

Answer (score 1):

If you are researching for a web-app, I strongly recommend you to check the various  realtime Stats/Analytics platform.

Google recently introduced real-time stats in Analytics and there are many apps like:
[chartbeat](http://chartbeat.com/chartbeat/)
[clicky](http://getclicky.com/)
[woopra](http://www.woopra.com/features/)

there are many more, just search for "real time analytics"